# DLL Hell(p) - Works on dev box, but not any othe

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll

3 Days of hair pulling. It just doesn't make any sense. I can't figure out what I've missed.

So I have this C#/WPF VS2013pro project I'm building that works fine on my Visual Studio machine: Win 8.1 x64 but fails due to 'dll not found' on any target PC I transplant it to.

It uses FreeImage, which has two DLLs:
FreeImage.dll - C++ that does all the work
FreeImageNet.dll - .NET wrapper to make like easy in C#
The two need to be in the same directory and preferably the same as the .exe - so they are.

My project is 64bit. I downloaded the source for FreeImage and compiled both DLL's for x64: First the CPP one, then the .NET one. Then copied them to the solution.
The .net DLL is referenced in my solution. The CPP does not reference, of course. Both are part of the solution and copy to the %outputdir% (Bin/Debug or Bin/Release) when the solution is built. The program runs fine in DEBUG and in RELEASE on my Development PC and the DLL methods do their job.

I copy the entire BIN directory to another PC running the same version of Windows, same updates, the works... The program runs but when a method is needed from the FreeImage.dll it fails with "unable to find dll".

[image]

[image]

To make sure I'm right about it using the dll from the BIN directory (and not from System32 or SysWOW64) on my VS machine I pull it out and run the app: Yep it fails.
I put it back and move the entire directory: It works
I pull it out: It fails
I put it back and move it to a thumbdrive: It works
{you get the idea}
So at this point it sure seems like it is really using the one in the same directory as the .exe and the .NET wrapper dll

I move the thumbdrive with the code that just worked on my VS machine to the other PC: It fails.

Next I try remote debug to the other PC: All the files copy to a matched directory, debugging starts and works, I get output and breakpoint behavior from the remote PC: Only the calls that require the DLL again fail because FreeImageNet.dll cannot locate FreeImage.dll

I did nothing special on my Visual Studio machine to make FreeImage work: I downloaded the source and compiled then copied the DLLs to the solution and referenced the .NET dll - That's it.

I have Googled, and researched and opened questions on SourceForge about it. 
Every previous question I have found on this issue are cases of someone thinking FreeImageNet.dll was self-contained and not realizing it had to be located along side of FreeImage.dll

- I have checked registry for I have checked registry for    HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Control/SessionManager/KnownDLLs/
- I have tried to register it with regsrver32 (yes, the 64bit flavor)
- I have tried setting an environmental variable to it.
- I have tried copying the DLL to every directory that is part of the DLL search order.
- I have tried it on Win8.1x64pro (same as my Visual Studio pc) and two Win7x64pro machines.

I have assumed it was some weird quirk in 3.16 of FreeImage and done this again and again with previous releases as far back as 3.6, all with the same results.

I have built an installer for the solution and installed it on the VS machine where it worked, and installed it on the test machine where it failed.

I am trying for the first time (and not so successfully) to virtualize my physical PC. VMware has always been good to me for test environments and at this point I want to see if a total clone of the Visual Studio machine will succeed or fail with this project.

So... Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I might have skipped some parts of your question while reading, that's why I'll just ask my question: have you checked [`Process Monitor`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) (the new FileMon) to see what file(s) could not be found? Maybe FreeImage just needs a dependency like the correct vcredist...

Comment: Agreed with Process Monitor to check what (and where) DLLs are being missed.  in the windows SDK there is a package called depends.exe - that can help too.  Typically a dev machine has debug dlls, which are easier to debug through.  MS license does not allow these to be re-distributed.  Check that the DLLs are not debug binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Darn it, I missed one: vcomp120.dll

Seems it is part of the Visual C++ redistributable that was installed with Visual Studio.

It should have dawned on me that I would need to include this, but with the entire EMGUcv package working... and the fact that I hate C++ and haven't used it in a dozen years... It totally never occurred to me.

Comment: Told ya, vcredist! :)

Answer (score -2):

Can you please try to import the dll with DLLIMPORT. Copy and place the dll to the directory same as of exe and use following code in Code behind:

```
[DllImport("FIBITMAP.dll")]
public static extern void Load(string param1,string param2,...);
```

Here Param1, Param2,... will be your parameters to the function Load.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see what you're trying to fix with that

Comment: I thought, there may be a problem while importing the dll by adding it as reference. Couple of times I had that issue too.. So I just want to suggest him other approach to do the same. May be I misunderstood the Question.